# rails where for checking multiple condition

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-relation

Is there any short way to right following query in rails:

```
Message.where("(user_id = 8 AND  commentable_id= 84) OR (user_id=84 AND commentable_id=8) ")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

`arr = [8, 84]
Message.where(user_id: arr, commentable_id: arr)`

Above query will have 4 combinations:

user_id      commentable_id

1. 8              8
2. 8              84
3. 84            8
4. 84            84

Out of above combinations, 1st and 4th are invalid. Thus it should get you results.

Comment: Cool :). BTW its varunvlalan :D

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Arel is what you are looking for in terms of readability, like:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.user_id_and_comment_id user_id, comment_id
    where user_and_comment(user_id, comment_id).or(user_and_comment comment_id, user_id)
  end
  private
  def self.user_and_comment user_id, comment_id
    table[:user_id].eq(user_id).and(table[:commentable_id].eq comment_id)
  end

  def self.table
    self.arel_table
  end
end

Message.user_id_and_comment_id 8, 84
```

Extracting the stuff into separate models and a scopes helps composing queries a lot and makes them reuseable for other related queries.
Btw. I assume you did not hard coded the ids into the SQL.